# How to redirect url other than login_url when using user_passes_test in django decorators?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
url(r'^permission_not_granted/',views.permission_not_granted, name='permission_not_granted'),
```

this is inside decorators.py:
    def is_admin_or_senior_surveyor(user):
        return user.userrole.id == 1

this is the view method :

```
def permission_not_granted(request):
    return HttpResponse("Permission Not Granted")
```

Here is my permission:

```
@user_passes_test(is_admin_or_senior_surveyor,login_url=None,redirect_field_name='/permission_not_granted/')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `login_url` to specify the URL you want to redirect to:

```
@user_passes_test(is_admin_or_senior_surveyor, login_url='/permission_not_granted/')
```

You can also use the URL pattern name:

```
@user_passes_test(is_admin_or_senior_surveyor, login_url='permission_not_granted')
```

The `redirect_field_name` argument is used in the querystring e.g. `/permission_not_granted?next=/protected-url/`. This allows Django to redirect to the protected URL after the user has logged in on the login page. It defaults to `next`, and you shouldn't usually have to change it.

Comment: @joaquin please ask a new question and include your code, hopefully you’ll get an answer